# how to map table create at runtime?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

```
CreateTableQuery = "Create Table XYZ"; 
s.createSQLQuery(createTableQuery.toString()).executeUpdate();
```

now I would like map a table with JPA and Hibernate? Its possible?

Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA/Hibernate maps database tables to classes.

That means you would need a class that you can map the created table to.

If you already had this class then it's no longer dynamic.

For sure you could create a class at run-time using libraries and the try to generate the meta data of Hibernate. But I'm not sure if this is really your use case.

So my answer is NO it's not possible.